# flutter video player not showing video

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-video-player

In my app I have a video running in the background.
I have a parameter page with a filepicker button which saves the path of the selected video in sharedpreferences

```
Future<File> _pickVideo() async {
final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.video);

File file = File(result!.files.single.path ?? '');
if (file != null) {
  setState(() {
    pickedVideo = file;
    print('video $pickedVideo');
  });
}
return file;}
```

In the video player page i retrieve the sharedpreferences path and I can display it in a Text widget

```
Text(selectedVideoValue ?? '',)
```

when I want to use it in the video player it doesn't work.
am i doing something wrong?

```
String? selectedVideoValue;

if (selectedVideoValue != null) {
  controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File('{$selectedVideoValue}'))
    ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
    ..initialize().then((_) {
      controller.setVolume(0.0);
      controller.play();
      controller.setLooping(true);
      setState(() {});
    });
} else {
  controller =
      VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/movies/STYLEARCHIGRAPHIQUE.mp4")
        ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
        ..initialize().then((_) {
          controller.setVolume(0.0);
          controller.play();
          controller.setLooping(true);
          setState(() {});
        });
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Below Code set into initState() may be working

````
  controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File('{$selectedVideoValue}'))
    ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
    ..initialize().then((_) {
      controller.setVolume(0.0);
      controller.play();
      controller.setLooping(true);
      setState(() {});
    });
} else {
  controller =
      VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/movies/STYLEARCHIGRAPHIQUE.mp4")
        ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
        ..initialize().then((_) {
          controller.setVolume(0.0);
          controller.play();
          controller.setLooping(true);
          setState(() {});
        });
}```
````

Comment: it is already in the initstate()